# Using LINQ to connect with multiple databases

Tags: asp.net, database, nhibernate, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP.NET application in which I need to provide support for two databases, MySql and MS SQL Server 2005 and 2008 (one database will be used at a time).

1. How will I configure the ASP.NET app to connect with different databases without reinstalling the app (i.e. using configuration)?
2. How will I configure LINQ?
3. Shouldn't I use NHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is better way of doing it: [Multiple database support with Entity Framework](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Multiple-database-support-with-Entity-Framework.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use basic Linq to SQL structures (nothing database specific) and by just changing the connection string should do the trick. Linq expression trees are transformed to SQL by Linq enabled drivers (i.e. they know how to handle the expression tree).

Comment: There is a flaw in your suggestion. Linq to SQL (System.Data.Linq) does not support any database except SQL Server. Entity Framework (with a MySql Connector version of 6.x or above) or NHibernate do, though.